# cannot get one to many relationship working in (Flask-) SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have several classes:

```
import uuid
from app import db, create_app
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID, ARRAY, JSONB

class Ticket(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tickets'
    id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    time = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=func.now(), index=True)
    proposed_names = db.Column(ARRAY(db.String))
    measurements = db.relationship('TempMeasurement', back_populates='ticket')

class BaseMeasurement(object):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    @declared_attr
    def type_id(self):
        return db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('optical_data_types.id'))

    @declared_attr
    def type(self):
        return db.relationship('OpticalDataType')

    @declared_attr
    def operator_id(self):
        return db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('operators.id'))

    @declared_attr
    def operator(self):
        return db.relationship('Operator')

    @declared_attr
    def item_id(self):
        return db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey('items.serial'))

    @declared_attr
    def item(self):
        return db.relationship('Item')

    time = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True)
    instrument = db.Column(db.String)
    instrument_sn = db.Column(db.String)
    data = db.Column(JSONB)

class TempMeasurement(db.Model, BaseMeasurement):
    __tablename__ = 'ticket_data'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ticket_id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), db.ForeignKey('tickets.id'), index=True)
    ticket = db.relationship('Ticket', back_populates='measurements')
    original_paths = db.Column(ARRAY(db.String))
```

What I want/expect is that I can create a `Ticket` with several child `TempMeasurements` and commit this to the database.  Something like:

```
app = create_app()

with app.app_context():
    ticket = Ticket()
    ticket.measurements = [TempMeasurement(...)]
    db.session.add(ticket)   # <-- error on this line
    db.session.commit()
```

However, I get an obscure error deep in SQLAlchemy:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
```

with a full trace [here](https://pastebin.com/BQ9t3eqf).

I thought that it might be because the `UUID` ticket_id column has as_uuid, so I made it simply UUID (implicitly a `str`), but this did not solve my issue.

The error is too deep in SQLAlchemy for me to understand -- can anyone help?

Comment: What is `db.session`? I would expect that you have to open and close the session when working with it, rather than having an already opened session in a global variable... e.g. `Session = sessionmaker(bind=db_engine); session = Session()` and only then you use it.

Comment: `db.session` is a global managed by `Flask-SQLAlchemy` -- using the extension, you do not need to manually manage session creation and destruction, or engine binding.

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but it might help to first add `ticket`, perhaps even [`flush`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.flush) after that, and then add the `measurements `?

Comment: If I `add&flush` the ticket, then do `ticket.measurements = [...]; db.session.add(ticket)`, I get the same error.  It appears to be some kind of configuration error in my relationships.

Comment: If you leave out this line `ticket.measurements = [TempMeasurement(...)]` does it work?

Comment: yes -- the Ticket class itself is not malformed it seems, only the relationships.